# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass'

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.openMenuDeserts (App.js:135)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (App.js:5354)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (App.js:5162)
```

here's my code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class MenuDeserts {
  constructor() {
    this.openMenuButton = $(".open-menu-deserts");
    this.Deserts = $("#desertMenu");
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.openMenuButton.click(this.openMenuDeserts);
  }


  openMenuDeserts() {
    this.Deserts.addClass("menu-deserts--is-visible");
    return false;
  }

}

export default MenuDeserts;
```

if i replace the contents of  "openMenuDeserts() {}" with console.log it will show up in the console, but no matter what i put in there i keep getting that error. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On events function you are trying bind click event with your function. The click event will be triggered, but the problem that openMenuDeserts function is not binded to MenuDeserts. Best practice is to bind your function to "this" instance of the class in constructor.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class MenuDeserts {
  constructor() {
    this.openMenuButton = $(".open-menu-deserts");
    this.Deserts = $("#desertMenu");
    this.events();
    // bind the function to this in constructor
    this.openMenuDeserts.bind(this);
  }

  events() {
    this.openMenuButton.click(this.openMenuDeserts);
  }


  openMenuDeserts() {
    this.Deserts.addClass("menu-deserts--is-visible");
    return false;
  }

}

export default MenuDeserts;


There are 3 ways you can solve this issue:
1) bind the function to "this" instance in constructor of the class.
2) bind the function to "this" instance on where you triggering the function. 
Ex: 
    this.openMenuButton.click(this.openMenuDeserts.bind(this));

Note: This is will trigger bind every time the click is triggered.

3) Use fat Arrow function in click.
Ex: 

this.openMenuButton.click(()=> {
       this.openMenuDeserts()
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the click event eventually occurs and jQuery calls `openMenuDeserts()`, the value of `this` is not set to your object, it is set to the DOM element the click event occurred on. Use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to make sure your function is called with the right `this` value:

```
events() {
  this.openMenuButton.click(this.openMenuDeserts.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: thanks i actually had bind(this) on my actual code, i guess i deleted it while trying other sutff.  BUT i had just one ) and thats why it was not working, Im an idiot.